# How can I check if a word exists in a TF-IDF matrix in Python?

Tags: python, tf-idf

How can I check a word from the matrix of tfidf in Python programming?

This is the method that I used to make the matrix from the set of tokens:

```
def matrix_TF_IDF(doc):
    vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
    tfidf_matrix = vectorizer.fit_transform(doc)
    feature_names = vectorizer.get_feature_names_out()
    tf_idf_array = tfidf_matrix.toarray()
    words_set = vectorizer.get_feature_names_out()
    df_tf_idf = pd.DataFrame(tf_idf_array, columns = words_set)
    print(df_tf_idf)
    return df_tf_idf
```

Then I try to call this method after I find the tf and idf of that set of token. And it will show result like this form:

```
   adversari    alarum      alon      ambl      amor       arm  ...       web    wherea    winter    wreath    wrinkl      york
0   0.137854  0.137854  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.137854  ...  0.000000  0.000000  0.137854  0.137854  0.137854  0.137854
1   0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  ...  0.420502  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
2   0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.234126  0.234126  0.000000  ...  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
3   0.000000  0.000000  0.071247  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  ...  0.000000  0.142494  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000
```

This is the result of the matrix that I found from that function then next I would like to accept an input from the user and check that if the word is exist from the formed matrix and if it exist I would like to show the document name but I don't know how can I check the word from the matrix.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour] and [How to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask).